# Logic and reasoning

Tags: logic

If a person sprints up a staircase and walks the last 24 steps, he takes 28 seconds. If he sprints and walks the last 36 steps, he takes 30 seconds. How many steps are there in the staircase?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this, or on how to approach it?

Comment: No , I do not have any idea .

Comment: I doubt if the data suffices to give the answer .

Comment: Call $x=$ the speed when he walks, $y=$the speed when he sprints. Informations give you two equations, so that you have to solve a linear system.

Comment: Pick a more descriptive title than "Logic and Reasoning".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that walking and sprinting speed is *v* and *u* steps per second respectively. Then if the total number of steps is *n*, the equation would be:

$$\frac{24}{v} + \frac{n - 24}{u} = 28 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$\frac{36}{v} + \frac{n - 36}{u} = 30 \tag{2}$$

Multiply the first equation by $1.5$ and subtract the 2 equation. It will give:

$$0.5\frac{n}{u} = 12 \tag{3}$$
$$n = 24u \tag{4}$$

If you substitute *n* in equation $\eqref{1}$:
$$\frac{24}{v} + 24 - \frac{24}{u} = 28 \tag{5}$$
$$\frac{1}{v} - \frac{1}{u} = \frac{1}{6} \tag{6}$$
$$n = \frac{144}{6 - v} \tag{7}$$

This is all you can get. You can clearly see that   there is only 2 equation for 3 variables so you can make it only parametric equation at best. You need some relation between *u* and *v* or something like that to get an exact answer.